# ghostscript apt repository - install latest/newer version

Tags: linux, ghostscript, apt

If you install `gs` like `apt-get install ghostscript` then an older version (9.05) is installed but the latest version is 9.14

How to update the apt repository so I can install the latest version (or newer versions)

With Percona you can add their own repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list` like:

```
deb http://repo.percona.com/apt wheezy main
```

Is it possible to do something similar with ghostscript?

Is using Debian Wheezy

Comment: Which linux flavour you are using?

Comment: is using debian wheezy

Comment: kindly did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package for ubuntu.

http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-13.10/ubuntu-main-amd64/ghostscript_9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb.html

If you want latest and greatest version you should build it from source.